# why my React Typescript onChange Attribute work not Successful

Tags: reactjs, typescript

[Capture Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzCOq.png)

First sorry to upload my question using right form

My question is I want to see

```
event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>
```

But In my code when I cursor in onClick event I can only see

```
{React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement> | undefined}
```

So I erase Handler and it works
I wonder about why I only can see EventHandler not Event

I check for ohters code I can't find this

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

type MyFormProps = {
  onSubmit: (form: { name: string; description: string }) => void;
};

function MyForm({ onSubmit }: MyFormProps) {
  const [form, setForm] = useState({
    name: "",
    description: "",
  });

  const { name, description } = form;

  const onChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setForm({
      ...form,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    onSubmit(form);
    setForm({
      name: "",
      description: "",
    });
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input value={name} onChange={onChange} name="name"></input>
      <input name="description" value={description} onChange={onChange} />
      <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default MyForm;
```

Comment: Can you paste the code instead of the screenshot?

Comment: I upload my code

Comment: It's not clear what your actual question is (language barrier?). What is the *exact* problem you are having with the code you posted?

Comment: I changed my question about what I worder thing. Sorry to upload like this...